Two rival tags, [tpm] and [trusted-platform-module], both for the same topic. Neither is officially a synonym for the other
This is the description for the [tpm] tag:

A Trusted Platform Module (TPM) is a secure co-processor found in some PC-type computers that provides cryptographic operations and system integrity measurements.

And the [trusted-platform-module] tag:

A Trusted Platform Module (TPM) is a secure coprocessor found in some x86-based computers that provides cryptographic operations and system integrity measurements.

(I have submitted tag wiki edits for approval, since TPMs are not specific to x86 or to the PC platform. However, that's not what this post is about.)
Clearly, both of these tags cover the same topic - TPM chips. However, they are not synonyms for each other. One has seven questions, and the other has fourteen.
I believe that one of these tags should be made into a synonym for the other, and that the 21 questions should all be covered by this unified tag. Alternatively, one of the tags could be deleted and have its questions merged into the other tag.
(I'm not that familiar with tag "burnination", synonyms and the like. Please accept my apolgies for any mistakes I've made with the terminology.)
I would also like to suggest that [trusted-platform-module] should be the tag, and [tpm] should be the one that is either deleted or made into a synonym, since the former is more specific. For example, according to Wikipedia TPM could also stand for "Tivoli Provisioning Manager" or "Technical protection measures"!

You can now vote for your own answer. I'm pretty sure that we'll go for your solution, but hey, meta can do with some traffic.

Just voted now.

@MaartenBodewes I'm not often in Crypto meta, so I don't know when voting typically closes on these tag synonym questions. Could you tell me, or if there's an "advice for newbies" post anywhere that touches on it, point me to that?

Sometimes you just need to comment so you get some attention again. I'll try and pick this up on friday.

@MaartenBodewes With only two votes since I posted this on the 1st, both for my proposed solution, can I now use the green tick to mark it as the winning option?

Sure! Sorry but there is a lot going on in my life right now and sometimes I forget these kind of things. I'll put in in my agenda.

Agreed, these should be synonyms, and using tag [trusted-platform-module] is best because TPM can have multiple meanings. Note that typing tpm in the tags field will still result in the right tag to be added.

And it has been finally done, thanks for suggesting this.

Although this is an old question right now, I'm not sure if this has been done correctly. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm has "Tagged with [tpm] or [trusted-platform-module] ... 19 questions". But https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trusted-platform-module only has the subset of 12 questions that were tagged [trusted-platform-module], not the ones that were tagged [tpm].

It seems that this requires retagging: However, existing questions tagged with the synonym tag that were using it before the synonym was created and were not edited later will continue to use the synonym tag. As this is a moderate amount I'll check if I can do this the coming days.

I think I did this now, if you find anything tagged tpm let me know!

Thanks! It all looks good now.

Agreed, these should be synonyms, and using tag [tpm] is best because although TPM has multiple meanings, it is unlikely to be confused within the field of cryptography.

Nah, they should not be synonyms. The current situation is fine.
